# How to wait for a Java applet to finish loading on Safari?

Tags: javascript, java, safari, dom-events

This doesn't work in Safari:

```
<html>
<body>
<applet id="MyApplet" code="MyAppletClass" archive="MyApplet.jar">
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert(document.getElementById('MyApplet').myMethod);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`myMethod` is a public method declared in `MyAppletClass`.

When I first load the page in Safari, it shows the alert before the applet has finished loading (so the message box displays `undefined`) . If I refresh the page, the applet has already been loaded and the alert displays `function myMethod() { [native code] }`, as you'd expect.

Of course, this means that the applet methods are not available until it has loaded, but Safari isn't blocking the JavaScript from running. The same problem happens with `<body onLoad>`.

What I need is something like `<body onAppletLoad="doSomething()">`. How do I work around this issue?

PS: I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the JAR is signed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use a timer that resets and keeps checking a number of times before it gives up.

```
<script language="text/javascript" defer>

function performAppletCode(count) {
    var applet = document.getElementById('MyApplet');

    if (!applet.myMethod && count > 0) {
       setTimeout( function() { performAppletCode( --count ); }, 2000 );
    }
    else if (applet.myMethod) {
       // use the applet for something
    }
    else {
       alert( 'applet failed to load' );
    }
}  

performAppletCode( 10 );

</script>
```

Note that this assumes that the applet will run in Safari.  I've had some instances where an applet required Java 6 that simply hangs Safari even with code similar to the above.  I chose to do browser detection on the server and redirect the user to an error page when the browser doesn't support the applet.

Comment: Thank you. It's a shame there isn't a cleaner way of doing this!

Comment: You can also simply check for applet. At least, you can in Firefox. I haven't checked in Chrome & IE. That way, you don't have to modify the applet to have a particular method.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a generic function I wrote to do just this:

```
/* Attempt to load the applet up to "X" times with a delay. If it succeeds, then execute the callback function. */
function WaitForAppletLoad(applet_id, attempts, delay, onSuccessCallback, onFailCallback) {
    //Test
    var to = typeof (document.getElementById(applet_id));
    if (to == "function") {
        onSuccessCallback(); //Go do it.
        return true;
    } else {
        if (attempts == 0) {
            onFailCallback();
            return false;
        } else {
            //Put it back in the hopper.
            setTimeout(function () {
                WaitForAppletLoad(applet_id, --attempts, delay, onSuccessCallback, onFailCallback);
            }, delay);
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
WaitForAppletLoad("fileapplet", 10, 2000, function () {
    document.getElementById("fileapplet").getDirectoriesObject("c:/");
}, function () {
    alert("Sorry, unable to load the local file browser.");
});
```

Comment: You could also try document.getElementById(applet_id).isActive to test if the applet is loaded in the above example, it worked for me. :)

Comment: But if you do that, document.getElementById(applet_id) will return null when it doesn't exist, and then it will throw a null reference exception of ".isActive". I didn't want to have to test by exception, that is very, very slow in JS.

Comment: As far as my tests go, `typeof (document.getElementById(applet_id))` always return `object`. Did you mean `typeof (document.getElementById(applet_id).someFunction)` ?

Comment: I think that depends on what your applet is and how it's configured. You may have to test both the element and the function. You can't just test typeof (document.getElementById(applet_id).someFunction) by it's self, as document.getElementById(applet_id) may return null early in the life cycle, throwing an invalid object exception when trying to access .someFunction.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem some time ago and adding MAYSCRIPT to the applet tag solved my problem.

Take a peek at this page:
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/applets/_APPLET_MAYSCRIPT.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant to waiting for the applet to load. Also, the example on the page doesn't work in Firefox 3.5.4 on Snow Leopard.

Comment: AFAIU that only applies to IE.  In other words, not OS X & not Safari.