# Java Applet Loading (Lag)

Tags: java, html, applet

I have created a Java applet and some HTML code to load it using the object tag. The problem I have is however when the applet is loaded invoked when an user clicks a button, there is a 1 to 3 second lag, where you can't click anything on the page and the page freezes. Is this normal for loading Java applets? Do Java applets normally lag like this for a few seconds when they are loading. Is there a way to make the webpage act normally while the Java app does it work in the background?

Comment: Without example code, there is no way were ever going to be able to tell.

Comment: Try the following (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293355/how-to-wait-for-a-java-applet-to-finish-loading-on-safari) and keep your applet view hidden until it finishers loading