# Java 1.6 update 11 works on safari 5, but not java 1.6.25, why?

Tags: java, safari, applet

I'm now testing an applet application which required to work on JAVA 1.6 & 1.7

However i got a lot of difficulties with SAFARI & JAVA versions in-compatibility.

The test is for safari 5:

- i install jre-1.6.0_11 --> the applet loaded normally
- i install jre-1.6.0.25 --> the applet does not shown, no message for what's going on?

Updated

- i install jre-1.7.0_11 --> the applet loaded normally
- i install jre-1.7.0.25 --> the applet does not shown, no message for what's going on?

It's great if you can share your experience of this proble! Please tell if you have any solution that can detect if java is working or not?

Comment: Does it work on other browsers? Do other applets work on the problematic browser? Any code you think would be relevant that you could post?

Comment: Yes hexafraction, i only experience this problem in Safari. I think the code shouldn't be a problem, because i try to go to the SUN JAVA TEST PAGE, and the same result i got for SUN's applet!

Comment: Have you tried Java 6 update 45?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I haven't tried it out. Do you know where Apple or Sun publish these in-compatibility things?

Comment: I think you means http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/system-configurations-135212.html and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/config-417990.html  The later states safari 5.1.3 and above.

Comment: testing these versions is killing me softly. Our client want a message to show up in case of java is not working. The deployment toolkit & this one http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/Java/ does not give a support for checking if JAVA really work. They only can check if java is installed & enabled. What should i do if my plugin is installed & enabled, but java is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and it was a nightmare. Apple has been very strict with plug-ins like Java Applets and Flash due to security issues (specially after several Zero-day-attacks occurred this year [here](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2013/01/28/new-vulnerability-bypasses-oracles-attempt-to-stop-malware-drive-by-downloads-via-java-applets/) is an example).

There are two things you can do to avoid your applet being blocked by the web browser:

- Do not use javascript interactivity;
- Do not use access local system/file;

You asked:
*What should i do if my plugin is installed & enabled, but java is not working?*

You could create a javascript function to check if your applet was loaded (yes, it contradicts what I just said...). Here is an example:

[How to wait for a Java applet to finish loading on Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293355/how-to-wait-for-a-java-applet-to-finish-loading-on-safari)

Finally, did you check java security levels?

Cheers,

Comment: Using JS to test for the appearance and health of an applet is one of the few ways (besides the applet using a session to 'phone home' to the server to say 'launched') to distinguish between an applet that is just downloaded as opposed to one that successfully launched (got through `init()` & `start()`).